# Can I set priority of WiFi AP's on the same network as a user?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

The scenario is that I am an employee at a company where they have set up a network that spans the entire floor of the office. They have used a sort of mesh system so there is only one Wi-Fi network available to join that just grabs the closest and strongest signal AP.

This is all well and good, but it turns out my desk is located in a "dead zone" of sorts where I am just at the perfect spot in between two AP's and my device will try to connect to one and then the other depending on if someone is walking by or opening a door making one signal stronger or weaker slightly. This results in dropped signals and/or constant reconnecting of the Wi-Fi. I would rather be able to specify one of the AP's to stay connected to and avoid the reconnecting any time the signal fluctuates.

I am working on a windows device running Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: This is really a question for the Company as we cannot help with AP locations or other fixes.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I wouldnt think this is IT specific (other than asking them to move AP's physically) as I was just asking how to connect to a specific AP on the network. Thats not exclusively an issue to my company; what if I phrased it as being in my home?

Comment: Agree with @NickHallick, the question is whether you can stop Windows from jumping from one AP to the other; that's a question about using Windows. The settings happens to be corporate, but I've had the same issue on my home mesh.

Comment: Even if you knew what settings to change, you still have to ask IT to do it for you. That's their job.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows machines, you can change the "Roaming Sensitivity" (sometimes called "Roaming Agressiveness". By making it less aggressive, you can avoid the constant switchovers (at the risk of loosing the connection when the current AP becomes too weak).

Under Network Status, choose Change adapter options, right-click on the Wifi adapter, choose Properties / Configure / Advanced / Roaming sensitivity level. See below:

[image: change roaming sensitivity]

In addition, you can monitor which AP you are currently using, and steer it to a better one manually, using the WifiInfoView tool from Nirsoft (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html). You can even make a shortcut to go to your "favorite" AP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Ive changed the setting and will test it out throughout the day to see if it helps!